# while running this my code I encountered error: argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

```
#print('[*] define model ... ')

#nw, nh, nz = X_train.shape[1:]
nw = X_train.shape[1:]
print(nw)
nh = X_train.shape[1:]
print(nh)
nz = X_train.shape[1:]
print(nz)

# define placeholders
t_image_good = tf.placeholder('float32', [batch_size, nw, nh, nz], name='good_image')
t_image_good_samples = tf.placeholder('float32', [sample_size, nw, nh, nz], name='good_image_samples')
t_image_bad = tf.placeholder('float32', [batch_size, nw, nh, nz], name='bad_image')
t_image_bad_samples = tf.placeholder('float32', [sample_size, nw, nh, nz], name='bad_image_samples')
t_gen = tf.placeholder('float32', [batch_size, nw, nh, nz], name='generated_image_for_test')
t_gen_sample = tf.placeholder('float32', [sample_size, nw, nh, nz], name='generated_sample_image_for_test')
t_image_good_244 = tf.placeholder('float32', [batch_size, 244, 244, 3], name='vgg_good_image')
```

I got this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in make_shape(v, arg_name)
    144   try:
--> 145     shape = tensor_shape.as_shape(v)
    146   except TypeError as e:

9 frames
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in make_shape(v, arg_name)
    145     shape = tensor_shape.as_shape(v)
    146   except TypeError as e:
--> 147     raise TypeError("Error converting %s to a TensorShape: %s." % (arg_name, e))
    148   except ValueError as e:
    149     raise ValueError("Error converting %s to a TensorShape: %s." % (arg_name,

TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'.
```

how will I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with those `nw`, `nh`, `nz`. Let's take one, for example:

```
nw = X_train.shape[1:]
```

It is giving you error because it expects a single number when you use them in the code below, for example here `[batch_size, nw, nh, nz]`.

Let's take this example:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros((2,3,4))
print("Complete shape {}".format(array.shape))
print("Sliced shape {}".format(array[1:].shape))
```

As you can see the output is:

```
Complete shape (2, 3, 4)
Sliced shape (1, 3, 4)
```

By doing `[1:]` you are basically slicing an array, and the shape of it is a tuple (`(1, 3, 4)` in my example) and not a single number as it is expecting. You should provide something like you've done here `[batch_size, 244, 244, 3]` that is, an int.